# Dealing with singularity and overdispersion in GLMM?

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, overdispersion, offset

I'm running a GLMM through the lme4 package in R to detect differences in time spent feeding (response) before and after birth (my 2 categories in the variable inf_cat).
I started with a Poisson GLMM, with female ID as a random effect (because I have repeated measures) and an offset of the total amount of time observing the female in a block (to avoid using proportion values):

```r
ba.feed <- glmer(feeding ~ inf_cat + offset(total_inf_cat) + 
    (1|female), family=poisson, data=mothers_beforeafter)
```

The summary showed that my data had overdispersion so I switched to a negative binomial GLMM, but it gave me this error message:

```r
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

The summary shows that the variance of my random effect is 1.255e-11.

From my understanding, this singular fit comes from either a model that is too complex or not enough random effects levels. I've been troubleshooting with this [site](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1) but I'm still confused about what I can do moving forward. I don't think I'm able to simply drop my fixed effect variable and rerun the model because I have repeated measures in my dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The among-female variance (from the `(1|female)` term) and the overdispersion (from the NB fit) are sharing/competing for the variability around the fixed-effect values, so it's not surprising that the estimated among-female variance would decrease (in this case to zero) when you move to a NB model.

I don't see anything wrong with

```r
MASS::glm.nb(feeding ~ inf_cat + offset(total_inf_cat) + female, ...)
```

or

```r
glmmTMB::glmmTMB(feeding ~ inf_cat + offset(total_inf_cat) + female,
                 family = nbinom2, ...)
```

(i.e. converting the `(1|female)` random effect to a fixed effect of female). Or you could simply drop the `(1|female)` term (this should have no effect on the fitted model, as the among-female variance was already estimated as effectively zero.)

If you feel very strongly about keeping the random effect of female, *and* not wanting it to be singular, then you need to regularize (e.g. using the `blme` package) or go Bayesian (e.g. `rstanarm::stan_glmer()`, `MCMCglmm`).